# How to show data in crystal report using condition

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In my application, I am showing hospital data on crystal report. It includes patient name, reg. no., bill amount, Doctor name etc.

Now I want that, when Doctor name, changes, record should go on next page, i.e. each doctors record on new page. It is not necessary that all doctors appear on the record always.

Hope this question is clear.

Comment: Welcome to stackover flow please go thru FAQ link http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: I really like the sound of this application. It could really clean up the record keeping progress. Everything will be nice and organized if you use this. Bill | http://hallmarkhealth.org/Urgent-Care-Center/Page-2.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a doctor group in the crystal report and then force a new page. This will saw one doctor per page.

[group pics link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Crstalreportusingvs2010/Figure_14.jpg)